# Where should I put the code for refreshing access token with a DDD & CQRS manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs, mediatr

I am using ASP.NET Core and learning DDD & CQRS(including MediatR). I have read [eshopcontainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) documents. In my application, we need to store each user's access token & refresh token for google in our SQL DB, because we have to check some status in gmail periodicallly. 
When we implement the feature, more or less we would like to write following logic.

```
1. Get the access token and refresh token from our DB
2. If the access token is expired, we get the valid access token with refresh token
3. If the access token is updated in step 2, we save the new access token to DB
4. With the valid access token, we fetch information from gmail
```

This process will be used in several command handler in CQRS pattern.

My questions are,

- Where should I put the logic with DDD, CQRS manner? 
  Should it be put in repository, application service,or domain service...?
- Can we call the method from Query Handler? 
  I wonder this because that logic occasionally updates the data in DB, so I think we should not call this process from Query Handler

My current idea is creating a `UserService` that includes the process mentioned above. The concrete example of my solution structure is as follows. The `UserService` will be utilized in several command handlers, and will not be used in QueryHandler since it has occasional DB updates. However, if there is a better idea based on DDD manner, I would like to know it.

Solution structure

```
Application layer (depends on Domain and Infrastructure)
 - UserController.cs
 - CommandHandlers folder (several command handlers use UserService)
 - QueryHandlers folder 

Domain Layer (No dependency)
  - UserAggregate folder
    - User.cs (Model for user)
  - IRepository.cs (Interface)

Infrastructure Layer (depends on Domain)
  - EF Core related folder
  - Repository.cs (Implemented IRepository.cs)
  - UserService.cs (has the token update process)
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User 
{   
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public long Id {get; set;}
}
```

**UserService.cs (Just an idea)**

```
public class UserService 
{
    ....

    GetValidAccessToken(long userId) 
    {
        var user = repository.Find(userId);
        if (user.AccessToken is expired) 
        {
            var newAccessToken = GetNewAccesstokenWithRefreshToken(user.RefreshToken);
            user.AccessToken = newAccessToken;
            repository.Save(user);
        }
        return user.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is cross-cutting concern - try not to couple it with the domain logic. ASP NET middleware is good place to manage this. Also your application is really small to take advantage of DDD, Usually applications with small domains are pretty anoying to deal with when doing DDD due the separation. DDD is more suitable for complex domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Ankit Vijay.  Please do accept his answer as correct as I am only going to expand on that.

You typically use an access token in *integration layers* where you need to authorise the access.  Web APIs and other view controllers, for instance.  Message handlers, when using message queues, should not be exposed publicly so these would not typically require authorisation.

From what I can tell in your case you need to access an external store using an access token to obtain user-specific data.  This means that the access token may expire before that operation is attempted.

As I see it you have 3 options:

1) You obtain the relevant information at the initial integration point, say the web api controller, and then pass that data along.

2) You pass the user name along and use a *service account* of sorts to obtain an access token for the user where the service account has permission to do so on behalf of a user and then use the access token to obtain the relevant data.

3) It may be that the service account has the ability to gather this extra information for a user in which case the service account would authenticate to obtain a token and then request the data for the relevant user.

On a previous project that I was on we had to make use of a *webMethods* integration server where the back-end team were using an ADFS token.  The token had an 8 hour expiration and some operations ended up being performed only after this time for various reasons.  An expired token would be refreshed for the user since the service account had some form of delegation rights on ADFS.  I wasn't involved in that implementation but that was broadly the idea to circumvent the issue.

If you cannot have the service account refresh a token or obtain the required data directly I guess option (1) would be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Storing User access token and refreshing token does not appear to be a Business/ Domain concern. I would argue you should not be trying to handle it through DDD. If you need to access token in `CommandHandlers`, I would put the logic pertaining to the access token in some sort middleware outside of Domain.